# Jquery not method problem with button tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i don't why but the `not()` method of jquery return the same value for two differents tests that are exclusive.

Look:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(':button, :submit').filter(function() {
            $('#result').append('tag = ' + $(this)[0].tagName + "<br />");
            $('#result').append('.not(\':submit\').length = ' + $(this).not(':submit').length + "<br />");
            $('#result').append('.not(\':button\').length = ' + $(this).not(':button').length + "<br />");
            $('#result').append('.is(\':button\') = ' + $(this).is(':button') + "<br /><br />");

        });

    });

</script>

<button>Btn1</button>
<input type="button" value="Btn2" />
<input type="submit" />

<div id="result">
</div>
```

Here are the results :

tag = BUTTON

**.not(':submit').length = 0**

**.not(':button').length = 0**

.is(':button') = true

tag = INPUT

.not(':submit').length = 1

.not(':button').length = 0

.is(':button') = true

tag = INPUT

.not(':submit').length = 0

.not(':button').length = 1

.is(':button') = false

Found a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are confused by

```
.not(':submit').length = 0
.not(':button').length = 0
```

Your assumption is wrong, your tests are *not* exclusive. The jQuery documentation states:

> `:button`: Selects all *button elements* and elements of *type* button.
>   `:submit`: Selects all elements of *type* submit.

Now, it happens to be that `button` elements [have a `type` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) and the default value is `submit`.

> type = submit|button|reset [CI]
>       This attribute declares the type of the button. Possible values:
>
> - submit: Creates a submit button. This is the default value.
> - reset: Creates a reset button.
> - button: Creates a push button.

So jQuery returns the correct results. `not(:button).length` returns `0` because we are dealing with a `button` elements. `not(:submit).length` returns `0` because that button element as a `type` attribute with value `submit`.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is by design.  For the specific case of the `button` element, both the `:submit` filter and the `:button` filter are true.  `button` elements have the `submit` type by default ([see the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button)).

Answer (score 0):

Change filter(function() {}) to each(function(){}) then you may be in luck.

Comment: I use filter here because i was doing something when i had this problem, but both filter and each loop, so that's the same